# Having Trouble Writing A Small Shell Script That Creates A Dated Directory For Backup Files

Tags: mysql, cron, mysql-backup

I am trying to create a shell script as part of my cron job for my MySQL daily backups. I am using Webmin as the GUI interface and I was told to insert a small shell script as part of the Command to run after backup option in Webmin per noisemarine's response in this post: [https://www.virtualmin.com/node/54190](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIeUi.png).

Currently, I have to manually create a folder named after the current date (e.g. 6/6/2018) and move my four MySQL database backup files into this newly created folder. If I don't, the backup files will be overwritten by the next day's backup.

All my MySQL backups are stored in /etc/mysql/MySQL Backups/. Since I am still new to this, I need help in knowing which commands/script I need to perform for the following:

1. Automatically create a new folder each day named after the current date 
   (e.g. 6/6/2018) that's stored in the /etc/mysql/MySQL Backups/ directory.
2. Automatically move all four .sql backup files into the newly created folder 
   after an automatic MySQL backup (e.g. cron job automatically backups MySQL 
   and subsequently, the command used in the script will automatically move the 
   backup files into the 6/6/2018 folder)

I tried using the following commands separated by a ; as notated by noisemarine but to no avail:

BDIR=/etc/mysql/MySQL Backups/ ; DATE=`date +%F ; mkdir -p $BDIR/$DATE ;mv $BDIR/*sql $BDIR/$DATE/

I don't know what's wrong with this picture.

Again, it looks like all I need to do is insert a list of commands in the box titled  Command to run after backup option in Webmin (see attached image for visual representation).

Any help would be generously appreciated!

Thank you!

[Webmin Configuration screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIeUi.png)

Comment: Good heavens do not use `/etc` for bulk data storage, there should only ever be config files in there. A more appropriate location would be somewhere in `/var` or `/usr/local`.

Comment: Hi Sammitch. Thank you. I will keep that in mind going forward.